# Counting Rows in Excel based on optional filter conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to count the number of rows in excel based on multiple optional conditions. I am using `COUNTIFSF` function and it works, but as the conditions are growing up, the excel formula needs to consider all possible combinations, making the formula very large. I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Here is a sample for two filters (one per column), in both cases, I would like to consider each one of them could be optional. It is represented by the value: `ALL` on each cell:

[image: Sample using two optional filters]

I am using the following formula for cell `C10`:

```
=IF(
  AND(B1<>"ALL", B2<>"ALL"), COUNTIFS(TB[Col1],B1, TB[Col2],B2), 
    IF(AND(B1<>"ALL", B2="ALL"), COUNTIFS(TB[Col1],B1,TB[Col1],"*"), 
      IF(AND(B1="ALL", B2<>"ALL"), COUNTIFS(TB[Col1],"*", TB[Col1],B2), 
      COUNTIFS(TB[Col1],"*", TB[Col1],"*"))))
```

Where `TB` is the excel table object I created

In case I assign the value `ALL` to both filters it counts all the rows for a given column, for example, the scenario of `Filter1=ALL` and `Filter2=ALL` will return 6 and for: `Filter1=A` and `Filter2=ALL` will return the value: 2

As you can see, adding another filter and column will require 8 possible combinations to evaluate. In my real example, I would need 4 filters, so this solution doesn't escalate.

Another workaround would be adding additional unnecessary columns indicating which cells to consider (0, 1) based on the filter's values. It would imply having an additional column per filter condition. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do it, without using a pivot table.

**Note:** Adding a text representation to facilitate to reproduce it in excel:

```
Filter1 ALL     Col1    Col2
Filter2 ALL     A       AA
                B       BB
                C       CC
                D       DD
                A       AA
                D       DD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `IF`s inside the `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(TB[Col1],IF(B1="ALL","*",B1),TB[Col2],IF(B2="ALL","*",B2))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, Scott, It tried this, and I got an error, I thought I can't use this, probably I had an error with my formula. It works great!